# lazy load from node_modules in Rails 7 with ESBuild

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, esbuild, intl-tel-input

Is there a way to expose the `/node_modules/intel-tel-input/build/js/utils.js` script in a rails 7 app with esbuild?

The [intl-tel-input plugin](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input?tab=readme-ov-file#getting-started-using-a-bundler-eg-webpack) recommends lazy loading `utils.js` like so:

```js
import intlTelInput from 'intl-tel-input';

const input = document.querySelector("#phone");
intlTelInput(input, {
    utilsScript: "path/to/utils.js"
});
```

My problem is I don't know what the "path/to/utils.js" is.  I have tried `/node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js` `/intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js`, `/intl-tel-input/js/utils.js` but nothing in the node_modules directory is exposed to the browser.

Is there a way to expose `utils.js` using esbuild or rails asset path?

Comment: I think it needs to be path as in part of url

Comment: I realize that "path/to/utils.js" is a placeholder and i'm trying to figure out how to expose the javascript file in the node_modules directory so it can be lazy loaded when the page renders.

Comment: I don't believe there's a "rails way" to do it. You could simply copy the required file from node modules to public, even make it part of your deployment setup so it's always up to date

Comment: Thanks for that idea.  I'm currently just using the CDN as a work around, i suppose i could put `utils.js` in a public folder and make it part of my deployment.  I just feel like there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: Are you able to share your project via GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use asset helper to generate the path to utils.js

```
asset('intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js')
```

in addition, you can try to precompile to check for any errors while loading the js files.

```
rails assets:precompile
```

you might also add an event listener. Wost case scenario download the source code [here](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input/releases/tag/v19.5.6) and add it to public folder intl-tel-input-19.5.6/build/js/utlis.js

here is the example in public folder

[image]

```
    <script src="/intl-tel-input-19.5.6/build/js/utils.js"></script>
```

I know it is not a common rails practice but it's a workaround for packages.

Comment: I tried your suggestions.  While `asset()` is not a method, i found 'asset_path()` but got the error that `The asset "intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js" is not present in the asset pipeline.` even after running assets:precompile.

Comment: why don't you try to download the package from the link I provided and link it as a local asset in your public file. that's how I deal with some packages and it seems to work everytime. 
https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input/releases/tag/v19.5.6

Comment: Yes, that's an option @timjini, it's just not the answer I was hoping for.